# Blackberry - Auto scroll vertical field manager

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, scroll

How can I programatically scroll a screen in a specific direction without changing focus. For eg. as we scroll down to a Feed in FaceBook app, it automatically scrolls the screen to fit all the text in the center of the screen.

Can this be done in Blackberry Java Development ?

Thanks.
Afzal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do this if:

1. use [VERTICAL_SCROLL](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#VERTICAL_SCROLL) style in manager constructor (or [HORIZONTAL_SCROLL](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#HORIZONTAL_SCROLL))
2. use [setVerticalScroll(int)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#setVerticalScroll%28int%29) manager method (or [setHorizontalScroll(int)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#setHorizontalScroll%28int%29))